# iOS my App Extension sharing code with Pods properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension, podfile

I'm working on a signal based messaging app. I created a share extension and I need to use some of my pods in my share extension code. When I add these pods into my extension project, I get some errors. Because in some pods, it is used [UIApplication sharedApplication] object, which is NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS.    I did some searching but I couldn't find exactly what I want. This is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

abstract_target 'MyApp_pods' do
  pod 'Raven',                      :path => 'Raven'
  pod 'TextSecureKit',              :path => 'TextSecureKit'
  pod 'YapDatabase/SQLCipher',      :path => 'YapDatabase'
  pod 'OpenSSL',                    '~> 1.0.207'
  pod 'PastelogKit',                '~> 1.3'
  pod 'FFCircularProgressView',     '~> 0.5'
  pod 'SCWaveformView',             '~> 1.0'
  pod 'DJWActionSheet'
  pod 'JSQMessagesViewController',  :path => 'JSQMessagesViewController'
  pod 'CTAssetsPickerController',  '~> 3.3.0'
  target 'MyApp'
  target 'MyAppTests'
  target 'MyAppShareExtension'
end
```

Here is my question:

Is there any way to use these Pods in my share extension codes? Or is there any way to get some parts of pod contents (For example TSThread.m in TextSecureKit) ?

Comment: Did you got any way to solve it ?

Comment: I could not unfortunately. I was working in a company as an intern and internship was over. Did you find a way?

Comment: My problem is solved here. Refer this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462090/unable-to-use-pod-in-notification-service-extension/41477297?noredirect=1#comment70302049_41477297] if it helps you

Comment: Thanks. It would be helpful for me in my future works.