# Unable to use pod in Notification service extension

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoapods, moengage

I am creating a Notification extension, added target as per norm and added a pod in it as follows:

**Step 1 :**

```
target 'MyProject' do

   # Integration - Frameworks
   pod 'Fabric'
        pod 'Crashlytics'
        pod 'MORichNotification'
   end


target 'NotificationServices' do
    pod 'MORichNotification'
end
```

**Step : 2** 
Import "MORichNotification.h" into my Project bridge header file.

Now I want to use `MORichNotification` class in my `NotificationService` class, and it shows below error.
[image]

I tried with Clean project, Restarted, Wiped DerivedData, but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you imported module `MORichNotification` in bridging header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all MORichNotification is meant only for the Notification Service Extension, I can see from your podfile that you are including it in your app's target too.

And also you can use MORichNotifications, only if you are using [MoEngage-iOS-SDK](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MoEngage-iOS-SDK) in your app, as it will process only the notifications sent via MoEngage.

Now, follow the below steps to use MORichNotifications :

1. Install the MORichNotification pod in your Notification Service Extension. And please make sure that you are using version 1.1.1.
2. Add Bridging Header to your Notification Service Extension
   [image]
3. Import MORichNotification in Bridging Header as shown in the image below:

[image]

4. Use MORichNotification in your Notification Service Extension as shown below :
   [image]
   Let me know if still you are facing any issue.

Comment: Thanks that worked. My project gets compiled successfully. But still, when I run the app, MoEngage shows me the error : " Could not find a storyboard named 'MOInbox' in bundle NSBundle".

Comment: @nabu Which version of MoEngage iOS SDK you are using? And can you check and let me know if the storyboard file is present in the pod . refer -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0gpN.png

Comment: @ Chengappa C D I am using MoEngage-iOS-SDK 3.2.1, and storyboard is presented in pod resources.

Comment: @nabu : Check the link and make sure you have integrated MoEngage iOS SDK properly - > http://docs.moengage.com/docs/sdk-integration#section-integration-through-cocoapods

Comment: @nabu : I have released MoEngage-iOS-SDK version 3.2.2 with fix for MOInbox storyboard issue. Please update the SDK and let me know if still facing this issue.

Comment: Awesome - Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add your bridging header file on 'Build Settings'. I was able to use 'MORichNotification' doing the following steps.

1. Add entry to Podfile

`target "SOFAnswers" do
  pod 'MORichNotification'
end`

2. Pod Install
3. Create a Bridging header file with `PROJECT_NAME-Bridging-Header.h` with below contents.

> ```
> #ifndef SOFAnswers_Bridging_Header_h
> #define SOFAnswers_Bridging_Header_h
> #import <MORichNotification/MORichNotification.h>
> #endif /* SOFAnswers_Bridging_Header_h */
> ```

4. Configure the bridging header in build settings.
   (see attachment)

[image]

5. Use MORichNotification.h

[image]

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: R u using swift 3.0?

Comment: Yes Sahil I'm using 3.0, with latest XCode and iOS 10.2

Comment: Nice. hope this help nabu.

Comment: @Sri Still, you are trying to use it in your app. Now, try to create a notificationservice using this : [link](http://docs.moengage.com/docs/ios-10-rich-notifications) and follow the steps. let me know whether you are facing the same issue or not.